# Generating an enriched multicategory

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, operads, enriched-category-theory

Let $C$ be an $(M,\otimes,1)$-enriched category. I am looking for a reference for a notion of “generating the morphisms of $C$” (for ordinary categories, but also for multicategories, see below).

My attempt would be: A family $A:=(A(x,y)\to C(x,y))$ is called *generating* if for all $x,y$, the $M$-morphism
$$\Phi^x_y:\coprod_{x=e_0,\dotsc,e_n=y}\bigotimes_{i=1}^n A(e_{i-1},e_i)\to C(x,y)$$
is an $M$-epimorphism. For example, in the simplex category $\Delta$ (considered as $\mathbf{Set}$-enriched), the cofaces and codegeneracies generate the morphisms.

Likewise, for an $M$-enriched multicategory $O$, I would do the following: Each rooted tree $\Psi$ with edges labelled in $\mathrm{ob}(O)$ together with an enumeration of the incoming edges at each internal vertex gives at each such internal vertex $v$ an input/output profile $\binom{X(v)}{y(v)}$ with $X(v)\in\mathrm{ob}(O)^r$ and $y(v)\in\mathrm{ob}(O)$. If the “root edge” is $y$ and the “leaf edges” are $x_1,\dotsc,x_r$, we obtain a morphism
$$\Psi_*:\bigotimes_v O\tbinom{X(v)}{y(v)}\to O\tbinom{x_1,\dotsc,x_r}{y}.$$
So I would call a family $A:=(A\binom{x_1,\dotsc,x_r}{y}\to O(\binom{x_1,\dotsc,x_r}{y})$ *generating* if for all $x_1,\dotsc,x_r,y$, the $M$-morphism
$$\Phi^{x_1,\dotsc,x_r}_y:\coprod_{\substack{\Psi\text{ with leaves $x_1,\dotsc,x_r$}\\\text{and root $y$}}}\bigotimes_{v\in \Psi}A\tbinom{X(v)}{y(v)}\to O\tbinom{x_1,\dotsc,x_r}{y}$$ 
is an epimorphism. For example, consider $O:=H_*(\mathcal{C}_n;R)$, the homology of the little $n$-cubes, which is a one-object multicategory (so let’s write $O(r):=O\binom{\bullet\dotsm\bullet}{\bullet}$), enriched over $R\text{-}\mathbf{Mod}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. By Cohen, this is generated by
$$A(r) := \begin{cases}O(r) &\text{for } r=1,2\\0& \text{else}\end{cases}$$
My question is: Is there any reference for constructions like this, or a more elegant version? I don’t want to “reinvent the wheel”.